# Qual o código php utilizo para saber se os dados estão sendo recebidos de um determinado formulário?

Tags: php, formulário, script

Tenho dois formulários de busca. O primeiro com o nome "buscaid" o segundo "buscaimv" preciso de um código php que verifica se os dados estão sendo recebidos de um dos dois apenas, caso contrário será redirecionado para uma página específica.

Comment: olha o [manual do php.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.php): lá fala um pouco mais sobre uso de variáveis e sobre o método: `$_POST`

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma simples de fazer isso, apenas com o php/html é definir um hidden que identifique qual form acionado, nesse exemplo imagino que ambos usam a mesma action. Também é possível fazer isso com javascript.

Exemplo - simples.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="tipo" value="pf">
    CPF: <input type="text" name="cpf" value="111.111.111.11" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<form method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="tipo" value="pj">
    CNPJ: <input type="text" name="cnpj" value="222.222.222.222/22" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php

if($_POST['tipo'] == 'pf'){
    echo $_POST['tipo'] .'-'.  $_POST['cpf'];
}else if($_POST['tipo'] == 'pj'){
    echo $_POST['tipo'] .'-'. $_POST['cnpj'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Além da solução adequada postada pelo @rray, você pode usar os campos de submit para diferenciar os forms:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    CPF: <input type="text" name="cpf" value="111.111.111.11" />
    <input name="enviar_pf" type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>

<form method="post" action="">
    CNPJ: <input type="text" name="cnpj" value="222.222.222.222/22" />
    <input name="enviar_pj" type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>

<?php
  if( isset( $_POST['enviar_pf'] ) ){
     echo 'CPF: '.  $_POST['cpf'];
  } elseif( isset( $_POST['enviar_pj'] ) ) {
     echo 'CNPJ: '. $_POST['cnpj'];
  }
```

Note que no caso que você postou, nem isso precisaria, pois como há campos de nome direrente, pode testar diretamente por eles: `isset( $_POST['cpf'] )`

Uma alternativa que funciona perfeitamente apesar de não estar exatamente dentro das *specs*, é acrescentar um parâmetro de GET no POST:

```
<form method="post" action="?tipo=cpf">
    CPF: <input type="text" name="cpf" value="111.111.111.11" />
    <input name="enviar_pf" type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>

<form method="post" action="?tipo=cnpj">
    CNPJ: <input type="text" name="cnpj" value="222.222.222.222/22" />
    <input name="enviar_pj" type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>

<?php
  if( $_GET['tipo'] == 'cpf' ){
     echo 'CPF: '.  $_POST['cpf'];
  } elseif( $_GET['tipo'] == 'cnpj' ) {
     echo 'CNPJ: '. $_POST['cnpj'];
  }
```

Neste caso, note o action passando o "tipo" pela *query string* `?tipo=`